# If $T^rv=v$ and $v,Tv,\ldots,T^{r-1}v$ are linearly independent, every $r$th root of unity is an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, alternative-proof, symmetry

This is a self-answered question, which I think is a cute reference. Alternative answers are welcome, of course.

Let $V$ be  a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and let $T:V \to V$ be a linear map.

Suppose there exists a vector $v \in V$ such that $T^rv=v$, and $v,Tv,\ldots,T^{r-1}v$ are linearly independent. (In particular, this implies that $r$ is minimal, i.e. $T^kv \neq v$ for $0<k<r$).

> Then every $\lambda \in F$ satisfying $\lambda^r=1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

How to prove this claim?

---

*Comment:* This claim is false without the independence assumption. Take e.g. $T=-\operatorname{Id}$, and any $v \neq V$. Then $T^2v=v$, but $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from standard facts. From the given properties, $X^r-1$ is the minimal polynomial of the restriction of$~T$ to the minimal $T$-stable subspace$~W$ of$~V$ containing$~v$, the one spanned by $\{\,T^kv\mid k\in\Bbb N\,\}$. This minimal polynomial divides the minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ of (unrestricted)$~T$, so every root of $X^r-1$ is a root of $\mu_T$. Every root (in$~F$) of $\mu_T$ is an eigenvalue of$~T$. (Or you could avoid looking at the unrestricted$~T$ altogether: every root$~\lambda$ of $X^r-1$ is an eigenvalue of the restriction $T|_W$; in particular there are eigenvectors for$~\lambda$ of $T|_W$, and therefore of $T$, inside$~W$.)

For the record, the fact that every root$~\lambda$ of $\mu_T$ is an eigenvalue has a very explicit proof: write $\mu_T=(X-\lambda)Q$, then $Q[T]\neq0$ (by minimality of$~\mu_T$) and the image of $Q[T]$ is contained in the eigenspace $\ker((X-\lambda)[T])$ for$~\lambda$. In the example $Q=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}\lambda^{r-1-i}X^i$.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understood correctly, your proof does not rely on the  Cayley–Hamilton theorem, since you provided an easy direct proof that every root of the minimal polynomial is an eigenvalue, without referring to the characteristic polynomial. Am I right?

Comment: @AsafShachar Right, no characteristic polynomials anywhere in sight.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to your answer. Assume $I,T,\dots,T^{r-1}$ are linearly independent (no other assumption yet).

Let $\theta$ be nonzero. Of course,

$$ (\theta^{-r} T^r -I) = (\theta^{-1} T-I)(I+ (\theta^{-1}T) + \dots + (\theta^{-1}T)^{r-1}).$$

Now suppose $v$ is an eigenvector for $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\theta^{r}$. Apply both sides to $v$. The lefthand side is zero and the righthand side is $(\theta^{-1} T -I)w$ where $w=(I+ (\theta^{-1}T) + \dots + (\theta^{-1}T)^{r-1})v$. By assumption $w$ is nonzero, hence it is an eigenvector for $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. Can you please elaborate on why the sum $(\theta^{-r} T^r -I) = (\theta^{-1} T-I)(I+ (\theta^{-1}T) + \dots + (\theta^{-1}T)^{r-1})$ is invertible? I don't see how it follows from your independence assumption (or mine). Naively, I only see why it is nonzero.

Comment: I misread the question, making a conclusion based on an incorrect assumption. Fixed it. Only the conclusion part changes.

Answer (score 0):

Define $w=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \lambda^{-i}T^iv$.

$w \neq 0$ by our independence assumption, and direct computation gives (using $T^rv=v$) $Tw=\lambda w$:

$$
Tw=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \lambda^{-i}T^{i+1}v
$$

$$
\lambda w=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \lambda^{-(i-1)}T^iv.
$$

---

We can also reduce the argument to the case $\lambda=1$:

Write $S:=\lambda^{-1}T$. Then $S^r v=v$. Setting $w=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} S^iv$, we immediately get  $Sw=w \neq 0$, i.e.  $\lambda^{-1}Tw=w$ which is equivalent to $Tw=\lambda w$.

Answer (score 0):

I am elaborating and adding some comments and general perspective, based on Marc van Leeuwen's great answer:

We define $W=\operatorname{span}\{\,T^kv\mid 0\le k\in\Bbb Z\,\}$. Note that $\dim V < \infty$ implies $T(W) \subseteq W$ (since for some $k$, $T^kv$ is a linear combination of its predecessors $T^iv$ for $i<k$).

The assumption $T^rv=v$ implies $W=\operatorname{span}\{v,Tv,\ldots,T^{r-1}v\}$. Write $S:=T|_{W}:W \to W$.

**We have the following observations:**

*At the moment we do not assume linear independence of the $T^iv$ for $i<r$.*

1. **First, every eigenvalue of $S$ is an $r$th root of unity.** Indeed, the assumption $S^rv=v$ implies $S^r(S^kv)=S^k(S^rv)=S^kv$, so $S^r$ acts as the identity on the spanning set $\{v,Sv,\ldots,S^{r-1}v\}$ of $W$, thus $S^r=\operatorname{Id}=\operatorname{Id}_W$. But if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S$, then $\lambda^r$ is an eigenvalue of $S^r=\operatorname{Id}$, so $\lambda^r=1$  as required.
2. If we do assume $F$ is algebraically closed, then $S$ may not have posses any eigenvalue, e.g. rotation by $\pi/2$ in the plane. If $F$ is algebraically closed, then of course $S$ admits at least one eigenvalue, which must be a root of unity by the previous observation. Even in such cases $S$ may not have **all** the $r$th roots of unity $F$ as eigenvalues. Indeed, $S=-\operatorname{Id}$ and $r=2$ does not have the eigenvalue $1$. There can be dimensional reasons as well: If $S$ rotation by $\pi/2$, then $r=4$, but $S$ have at most two eigenvalues, even over $C$. (when considering $S:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$. SO if $r>\dim V$ of course we do not get all the $r$th roots of unity as eigenvalues.
3. **Finally, we now use the independence assumption of the $v,Sv,\ldots,S^{r-1}v$:**

We saw that $S^r=\operatorname{Id}$, i.e. $p(S)=0$, where $p(X)=X^r-1$. Thus, the minimal polynomial $m$ of $S$ divides $p$. We claim that the independence assumption implies in fact that $m=p$:

If $m \neq p$, then $\deg m < \deg p=r$, since if the degrees are equal $m-p$ is annihilates $S$ and has lower degree than $m$, which contradicts its minimality. Thus $m(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}a_ix^i$. $m(S)=0$ implies $\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}a_iS^iv=0$, so $a_i=0$, so $m=0$, which is a contradiction.

Since every root of the minimal polynomial is an eigenvalue, this shows every $r$th root of unity is an eigenvalue.

---